# VideoViewで動画再生を真ん中で再生させたい

Tags: android, android-layout

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Target Android OS: 4.0.3

`VideoView`を使って"横"画面最大に動画再生を行いたいです。
ただ、動画と画面のアスペクトが異なるらしく横端が黒くなります。それはいいのですが、足りない分を両端に均等に黒表示して動画を真ん中にもってきたいのです。現在は、以下のようにやっているのですが、動画が左詰めで足りない黒の部分が右端に出る形となっています。

`activity_main.xml`の`VideoView`部分

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

`main_activity.java`の動画再生部分　※動画は再生できております。

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
videoView.setVideoPath(setpath); // setpathに動画ファイルのパス
videoView.start();
```

対象方法ご存知の方はご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:gravity="center"`ではなく、`android:layout_gravity="center"`ではどうでしょうか？

また、親の`ViewGroup`の設定にもよるとは思います。例えば、

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

という場合、親の`FrameLayout`の領域内において、センタリングされることになるはずです。